# Solace Queue's expiry time

Tags: solace

I have the following code to set the expiry time on a message.

```
ObjectMessage message =...;
long expiration = 30*60*1000; //30 minutes

...

message.setJMSExpiration(expiration);
```

After 30 minutes, I am expecting the message to expire, and hence the subscriber will not be able to pick this message.

**Question :**
Will the message still sit in the Queue and available for browse?

Regards
Shankar

Answer (score 0):

The message will be spooled to the queue and will be available to be browsed until the expiry time is reached. At that point, the message will be removed from the queue and either discarded or sent to the DMQ, according to how the queue is configured.